# Difference between lambda-calculus with well-formed formulas vs properly-formed formulas

Tags: lambda-calculus, computability-theory

In S.C. Kleene's 1935 paper "$\lambda$-definability and recursiveness," he proves that all $\lambda$-definable functions are general recursive in the Herbrand-Godel sense and vice-versa. However, the exact choice of definition for $\lambda$-definable is a bit confusing for me. He differentiates between well-formed formulas (wff) and properly formed formulas (pff). Wffs are  pffs where in each properly formed part $\lambda x[M]$, $x$ must appear as a free symbol in $M$. For example, $\lambda x \cdot x$ is both a wff and a pff, but $\lambda x \cdot y$ is only a pff. He then goes on to define $\lambda$-definable functions using a Church encoding.

All modern sources that I've found on the $\lambda$-calculus are only concerned with properly formed formulas. Kleene himself notes in a footnote that by only considering pffs,

> ...simplifications are afforded in the
>   proofs of many theorems, but
>   unfortunately difficulties are
>   introduced in the formal logics in
>   which this theory is used. Rosser has
>   shown that the formal definition ($\lambda$-K-definition) under this program is equivalent to $\lambda$-definition, when the range of the independent variable is the set of natural numbers, and all the values have the same free symbols. For functions over all well-formed formulas, $\lambda$-K-definition is not equivalent to $\lambda$-definition, but we conjecture that the equivalence holds for many other significant ranges...

I would like to know more about this. It seems that what we today call the untyped $\lambda$-calculus was the $\lambda$-K-calculus to Kleene and Church. I can see why many of the proofs are much simpler in the $\lambda$-K-calculus.  My questions are:

What do we gain by only considering the well-formed formulas ("difficulties are introduced in the formal logics...")?

Does the equivalence still hold between $\lambda$-K-definable functions and Herbrand-Godel general recursive functions?

If so, is there a more modern paper or textbook that shows this using simpler proofs?

Comment: I asked a related question [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16508/are-the-lambda-i-calculus-and-the-lambda-k-calculus-equivalent), which may be of use.